# Guake disappears after being minimized

Tags: guake

I'm having a problem with Guake.

When I accidentally use the hotkey to minimize and the focus is on Guake, it minimizes, this is not the problem, the problem is that I don't know how to recover it.

If I execute Guake nothing happens, I have to kill the process to be able to use it again. Killing the process also means losing all the previously opened guake tabs, processes running in them, etc.

Comment: Can you alt-tab to it? I had this with some of MATLABs windows but they are still available by alt-tab.

Comment: I am having a similar problem under Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander), but not exactly as is described. If you would like to replicate the problem I'm experiencing (and maybe Federico's problem as well), open guake, and then press the the show desktop button. [This is a confirmed bug with guake](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/guake/+bug/1223650) , but the problem is I never use or press the show desktop button (only discovered this after trying to make this comment somewhat more of an answer). I also looked up the show desktop shortcut just to make sure I'm not triggering the bug by a

Comment: Can confirm. This exact problem occurs if I accidentally use ALT+TAB instead of the designated hotkey. And then the hotkey refuses to bring it back up. I have to kill guake to get it to show again. Answer with a fix below. Apparently, there's a CCSM option to hide all windows not in taskbar. Guake is not in the taskbar and so CCSM hides the window when this option is selected. The solution is to disable the CCSM "Hide Skip Taskbar" option.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it, the **Toggle Guake visibility** shortcut (defaults to F12) brings it back no problem. I guess you are used to opening guake just by clicking on its icon, not using F12.

**EDIT**:

More precisely you have to press F12 twice to bring it back from minimized state.

Comment: After hitting shortcut twice the title bar says "Guake Terminal" I have to click on the maximize button (up left) and it appears again. The weird part is that the maximize button works, but not the associated hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

There was [a bug opened on the github page](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/540#issuecomment-151403225) and when using CompizConfig Settings Manager on the Unity desktop, you can:

Open CCSM, and then uncheck the option for: **General** > **General Options** > **Hide Skip Taskbar Windows**

[image: this is a screenshot of the CompizConfig Settings Manager General Options tab showing the mouse cursor hovering over the unticked box for the Hide Skip Taskbar Windows option. The popup hint menu reads Hide windows not in taskbar when entering show desktop mode. This box should be unticked or unchecked]