# Guake disappears randomly on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, guake

I use dual monitors with a static Guake terminal on one while doing everything else on the other. Guake will work for a seemingly random amount of time, and eventually disappear until I reboot or kill the process (which loses any open tabs).

I found a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389487/guake-disappears-after-being-minimized), but it seems to be completely unrelated.

Comment: To debug this, stop `guake` from starting automatically and instead launch it from a terminal. Leave it running and when it crashes, copy any error messages and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the show desktop button which is a [confirmed Guake bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/guake/+bug/1223650). I never use the show desktop button from the sidebar, but realized later on that accidentally selecting show desktop while alt-tabbing is very easy to do (more so if you're unaccustomed to the alt-tab behavior brought about in 12.04).

I found [a temporary fix](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/45#issuecomment-35498929) as outlined by Stibbons by using "Hide on lose focus" in preferences. Keep in mind this will only prevent the alt-tabbing show desktop bug, and isn't ideal if you require a static terminal on a separate monitor. (I've disabled the sidebar button in settings > appearance > behavior - just in case!)

Stibbons said 19 days ago "I'll try to fix it asap," and as I was losing current tabs every few hours this temporary fix is HUGE timesaver.

Answer (score 6):

There's an [even better workaround in that thread](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/45#issuecomment-46593300) that lets you get the running guake back without restarting it, by `mbondfusion`:

1) Use `xwininfo` to find your root window ID

```
xwininfo -name 'Guake!' -int -tree

xwininfo: Window id: 60817461 "Guake!"

Root window id: 143 (the root window) (has no name)
Parent window id: 143 (the root window) (has no name)
1 child:
60817462 (has no name): () 1x1+-1+-1 +64+23
```

2) Use `xdotool` to reparent the Guake window:

```
xdotool search --name 'Guake!' windowreparent 143
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this problem is to disable the "Show Desktop" in the switcher with the unity tweak tool. It is easily installed with `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`
as explained in [How can I remove "Show Desktop" from the Alt-Tab (application) switcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167263/how-can-i-remove-show-desktop-from-the-alt-tab-application-switcher).